# Exception occurring not inside controllers/services, not reported

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I noticed that exceptions occurring not inside controllers/services but in plain javascript code is not being reported, doesn't appear in the console and can't be handled. For example, if I have Car class, which is being invoked from controller or service and there is exception inside the Car class, Angular will not report this error and swallow it.

Function Car {

```
this.drive = function() {
    // exception occurs here
}
```

}

Any idea on how to catch those exceptions? I'm using Angular 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

you have to throw those exceptions then only it will be caught in services or controllers

```
try {
 throw 'myException'; // generates an exception
 }
 catch (e) {
  // statements to handle any exceptions
   logMyErrors(e); // pass exception object to error handler
  }
```